# Deployment of Laravel project on Debian 9 using nginx

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, deployment, debian

I try to deploy my Laravel project from localhost to Debian server using nginx. First of all, i followed this tutorial [LINK](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04#prerequisites). Ended at the end of 5. chapter. I did not get any errors. Also I successfully connect Laravel project with server DB. I use Laravel version 6, so when i was modifying newly created config file on /etc/nginx/sites-available/myFile I used laravel's deployment tutorial [LINK](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/deployment). As my server does not have any domain, I've got only IP available. Screenshot of my config file:
[Config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cWPH.png)

When I try to open server page using IP, i got error "This page isn't working". It's because i deleted nginx's default file from sites-enabled. Before, i deleted the default file, i got only default home page of nginx.

I tried to change server_name like `server_name _;`, `server_name "";`, `server_name IP`. After all changes i restarted nginx server.

Any help how to run my Laravel project please? Thank you!!

EDIT: route to project: /var/www/html/OciNaCeste/BP_final

Comment: can you run `nginx -t`?

Comment: What is the error code when your page says `not working`?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert yes, test was successful

Comment: @ChristopheHubert there's no error code, This page isn’t working myIP didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please use the following configuration

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/OciNaCeste/BP_final/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

1. Then restart nginx

Comment: try to replace the full configuration by the updated content of the answer

Comment: Error after restarting: `nginx: [emerg] no port in upstream "php-upstream" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/OciNaCeste:35`

Comment: which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: My installed php version on server is 7.4.5, i see that i use php 7.2.29 on my localhost

Comment: can you check which version of fpm you are using? `dpkg --list | grep php`

Comment: Then please try again the configuration (I cleaned it up and changed the php-fpm version which should be `7.4`)

Comment: Here is the result of `dpkg --list | grep php`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d8YG.png

Comment: yup, as I expected, `php7.4-fpm` - how is the latest configuration looking?

Comment: Alright, the feeling is good, right? I do remember struggling like crazy with my first Nginx configuration  - Have fun!